# Parsing xml causing match error with new line

Tags: scala, xml-parsing

Hi trying to parse xml with pattern matching 
to the following classes :

```
sealed trait Predicate
case class Single(name:String) extends Predicate
case class Or(ps: Seq[Predicate]) extends Predicate
case class And(ps: Seq[Predicate]) extends Predicate
```

this is my parser

```
object RuleParser {
  def parse(ns: NodeSeq):Predicate ={
    println(ns.toString())
    ns match  {
      case <AND>{ xs @ _* }</AND> => And(xs map parse)
      case <OR>{ xs @ _* }</OR> => And(xs map parse)
      case <name>{ s @ _* }</name> =>Single(s.text)
    }
  }
 }
```

however when I send this

```
 val elm1 =
      <AND>
        <name> John </name>
      </AND>

    RuleParser.parse(elm1)
```

**I am getting pattern matching error. 
BUT when trying with this:**

```
val elm2 = <AND><name> John </name></AND>
RuleParser.parse(elm2)
```

it is ok .

why is that ? 
the problem is that I am reading a file and it is structured with multiple lines (like elm1)

I tried also loading the file like this

```
  val src = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/home/buzz/foo.xml")
  val fxml = ConstructingParser.fromSource(src, false).document.docElem
RuleParser.parse(fxml)
```

but got the same problem

any ideas how can I resolve this ?

BTW I am using 2.11.4

Comment: What is `elm`? The result of `fromSource` is `fxml`.

Comment: @som-snytt yes, thank you for your comment , I fixed id. it should be RuleParser.parse(fxml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bible has [a section describing pattern matching](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/working-with-xml.html#26.8) literals in the presence of white space text nodes.

Illustration:

```
scala> <X>
     |      <Y/>
     |   </X>
res0: scala.xml.Elem =
<X>
     <Y/>
  </X>

scala> .child
res1: Seq[scala.xml.Node] =
ArrayBuffer(
     , <Y/>,
  )

scala> val xml.Text(s) = res1(0) 
s: String =
"
     "
```

The library's MarkupParser has the option to turn off "preserve whitespace," which you use in your example. That should just work.

For example:

```
import scala.xml._, parsing._

sealed trait Predicate
case class Single(f: String => Boolean) extends Predicate
case class Or(ps: Seq[Predicate]) extends Predicate
case class And(ps: Seq[Predicate]) extends Predicate

object RuleParser {
  def parse(ns: NodeSeq):Predicate ={
    println(s"Parse: ${ns.toString}")
    ns match  {
      case <AND>{ xs @ _* }</AND> => And(xs map parse)
      case <OR>{ xs @ _* }</OR> => And(xs map parse)
      case <name>{ s @ _* }</name> =>Single(_ == s.text)
    }
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  val src  = scala.io.Source.fromFile("foo.xml")
  val fxml = ConstructingParser.fromSource(src, preserveWS = false).document.docElem
  //val fxml = ConstructingParser.fromFile(new java.io.File("foo.xml"), preserveWS = false).document.docElem
  println(RuleParser.parse(fxml))
  val e1 =
         <AND>
           <name> John </name>
         </AND>
  println(RuleParser.parse(e1))
}
```

with foo.xml:

```
<AND>
                    <name> John </name>
                    </AND>
```

produces:

```
Parse: <AND><name>John</name></AND>
Parse: <name>John</name>
And(List(Single(<function1>)))
Parse: <AND>
           <name> John </name>
         </AND>
Parse: 

scala.MatchError: 
            (of class scala.xml.Text)
    at xmlp.RuleParser$.parse(xmlp.scala:14)
```

Comment: tried that. you can see in my example val fxml = ConstructingParser.fromSource(src, false).document.docElem
RuleParser.parse(fxml) , still yields match error

Comment: But you are correct - the problem is with the whitespace which can be solved with scala.xml.Utility.trim(elm)

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you don't appear to be dealing with the text nodes that occur inside the `AND` element before and after the `name` element.

Comment: why ? the parser is getting called recursively  .

Comment: Because in Scala, when you use `match` you have to handle all the cases that might occur, or you'll get a `MatchError`. `elm1.child.map(_.getClass) = ArrayBuffer(class scala.xml.Text, class scala.xml.Elem, class scala.xml.Text)` – have a think about this: where in your code are you handling the `Text` nodes? It's important to understand how the language you're using works; maybe it's worth revisiting the section on pattern matching in whichever introductory tutorial you're following.

Comment: You are missing the point. elm2 works fine while elm1 yields match error .although they are XML wise identical - i.e having the same elements . I simplified the Single class for the matching to handle simple string but still ...the same

Comment: You are underinformed about XML. There are text nodes before and after name in elm1 that you have made absent in elm2. The documents you have posted are not the same.

Comment: I may have misunderstood you. If you are handling the text nodes, where is the code doing so?

Comment: The problem was actually with whitespace which is afak is a known issue and can be solved using scala.xml.Utility.trim(elm)